# Asymptotic estimate of the probability of $(n, P(\sqrt{x})) \leq x$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $P(x)$ be the product of all primes less or equal to $x$. The probability of $(n, P(\sqrt{x})) \leq x$ for an arbitrary $n$ is then given exactly by
$$
\prod_{p\mid P(\sqrt{x})}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)} \sum_{ \substack{ {d \mid P(\sqrt{x}) } \\ {d\leq x} } } 
\prod_{p\mid d}(p-1)^{-1}.
$$

> > Q: Is there a known asymptotic estimate for this expression? (Or does someone know how to prove one?)

ADDED: Since I got one answer suggesting the asymptotic estimate lying close to 1, I'll add a few comments here as to why I anticipate the asymptotic estimate to converge to zero. First of all, the number of divisors of $P(\sqrt{x})$ grows as $2^{\pi(\sqrt{x})}$. The number of these divisors that are smaller than $x$ only grows polynomially (presumably read this on Terence Tao's blog, but might be wrong—anyhow seems consistent with numerical data), so that eventually, this subset of divisors has measure zero compared to the full set. Also, for any fixed divisor $d$, the probability of $(n, P(\sqrt{x})) = d$ is
$$
\prod_{p\mid P(\sqrt{x})}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}  
\prod_{p\mid d}(p-1)^{-1},
$$ 
which goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity. It therefore seems reasonable that the probability of $(n, P(\sqrt{x})) \leq x$ should tend to zero, albeit slowly. This result would also seem in accordance with the Erdös-Kac theorem, stating the number of divisors of $n$ has asymptotic mean equal to $\log \log n$. I've added some numerics below that might be suggestive in the direction I've described.

[image]

Comment: I must be a bit dense, but how come the expression has no $n$?

Comment: It's the probability that a random $n$ is coprime to $P(x)$ [that is, the limit as $N \to\infty$ of the probability that a number $n$ chosen uniformly at random from $\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$ is coprime to $P(x)$].

Comment: What if $x$ was slowly growing with $N$ say $x(N)=\log N$, or even $x(N)=\log \log N$, what would happen then? I apologise if this is inappropriate for a comment and can post a separate question in that case.

Comment: [correction: $n$ not necessarily coprime to $P(x)$ $-$ or rather, to $P(\sqrt x)$ $-$ but having no common factor  larger than $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $f_p(n)=\log(p)\cdot {\textbf 1}_{p|n}$. Your event is $\sum_{p^2<x} f_p<\log x$. The random variables $f_p$ are independent, so this is a sort of law of large numbers for not identically distributed, but still independent random variables.Sum of means grows as $\log(x)/2$, thus your probability should be close to 1.

UPDATE. My intuition got wrong, since the sum of our random variables has really huge variance. Namely, the expectation equals $$M:=\sum_{p<\sqrt{x}} \frac{\log p}p\sim \frac{\log(x)}2$$, and the variance equals $$\sigma^2=\sum_{p< \sqrt{x}} \frac{\log^2 p}p-\frac{\log^2p}{p^2}\sim \frac{\log^2x}8.$$
If CLT holds in this situation (I hope so, please check), then the probability of the event $\sum f_p(n)\geqslant \log x\sim M+\sqrt{2}\sigma$ should tend to 
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\sqrt{2}}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt={\rm erfc}(1)/2=0.0786\dots,
$$
thus your probability tends to $0.921\dots=1-{\rm erfc(1)/2}$.

Comment: The events "$n\le x$ is a multiple of $p$" for various $p$ are perhaps approximately independent for $p\ll x$ wrt to the uniform prob measure on $[1,x]$ (whatever the precise meaning of that might be), but not exactly.

Comment: @ChristianRemling If we consider residues modulo $P(\sqrt{x})$, they are independent. It is a usual understanding of such things.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the setup properly. But I don't seem to be able to come with a prob space + measure that makes your $f_p$ independent rv's.

Comment: PS: Or are you not making a technical claim at all, just describing an intuitive model?

Comment: Probability space is the (finite) set of residues modulo $P(\sqrt{x})$, all residues have equal probability.

Comment: Then the event "$p|n$" isn't even well defined because it depends on the representative $n$ of a given residue class.

Comment: Or if you just put the uniform distribution on $1,\ldots , N$, then for example "$97|n$" and "$2|n$" are not independent for $N=100$ (this is what I was trying to say in my first comment).

Comment: In our situation it is well-defined, since we consider prime divisors $p$ of $P(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks for your answer. I'm not entirely sure what your setup really means, and why you seem to be summing only over $p^2$. Also, I was a bit surprised by your conclusion, as it seems to go against the grains of the Erdös-Kac theorem. In fact, I had anticipated the asymptotic probability to converge to zero. I've added some more information to the question to clarify why I believe so.

Comment: This $p^2$ may be misleading, it is a way to write $p<\sqrt{x}$. Summation is over all such primes, of course.

Comment: Ok. But if I now understand you right it seems your event is not the same as mine. $f_p(n)$ considers all the cases where $p|n$, even those where the $(n,P(\sqrt{x}))>x$. If that is so, that is not the same as in my question, where each divisor of $P(\sqrt{x})$ is considered separately.

Comment: $\sum_{p<\sqrt{x}} f_p(n)=\log (n,P(\sqrt{x}))$, right?

Comment: Ah, reason finally dawned on me. You're absolutely right, and proved my intuitive guesswork wrong...good lesson to take. Both answers greatly appreciated and with the update on this question, I got what I hoped for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

We can show at least that your expression tends to a constant strictly greater than $0$. (Well, what we'll actually show is that its lim inf is positive.)

First we claim that
$$
\sum_{d\le w} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)} \sim \log w.
$$
This follows from standard tools for sums of multiplicative functions; for example, you can apply Proposition A.3(a) of [my paper](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/AFNSVP.pdf) with $g(n) = \mu^2(n) n/\phi(n)$ (but this result certainly isn't due to me; it can be found in Friedlander/Iwaniec's *Opera de Cribro*, for example).

In particular,
$$
\sum_{\substack{d\mid P(\sqrt x) \\ d\le x}} \prod_{p\mid d} \frac1{p-1} \ge \sum_{\substack{d \text{ squarefree} \\ d\le \sqrt x}} \prod_{p\mid d} \frac1{p-1} = \sum_{d\le \sqrt x} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)} \sim \log \sqrt x.
$$
Since of course
$$
\prod_{p\mid P(\sqrt x)} \bigg( 1-\frac1p \bigg) = \prod_{p\le\sqrt x} \bigg( 1-\frac1p \bigg) \sim \frac1{e^\gamma \log\sqrt x}
$$
by Mertens, we conclude that
$$
\prod_{p\mid P(\sqrt x)} \bigg( 1-\frac1p \bigg) \sum_{\substack{d\mid P(\sqrt x) \\ d\le x}} \prod_{p\mid d} \frac1{p-1} \gtrsim \frac{\log\sqrt x}{e^\gamma \log\sqrt x} = e^{-\gamma} > 0.
$$